# Subscribe to multiple topic destination in ActiveMQ Messaging

Tags: java, activemq-classic

A publisher publishes messages to different destinations. My client needs to subscribe and get all those messages in those destinations one by one.Means i want to consume messages from multiple topics. Also I want the topic messages (different destinations) to be received in a button action, not by using Message Listener. Can anyone please help on this?
Part of my code is.

```
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    if (isDurableSubscription) {

        // the subscription Name assigned to a durable subscription must be unique within a given client ID.
        consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber( topic, subscriptionName );  
    } else {
        consumer = session.createConsumer( topic ); 
    }

    log.finest("consumer = " + consumer );

    consumer.setMessageListener( this );

    conn.start();
```

}

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if ( message instanceof TextMessage ) {

        try {
            TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage) message;

            String text = txtMessage.getText();
            this.msg = text;
            System.out.println(text);
            log.finest("Message processed ...");

            session.commit();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also i want the topic messages (different destinations) to be
>   received in a button action, not by using Message Listener.

The whole point of a JMS provider is to listen to messages published by a producer and have an async communication channel in which the producer and the listener are decoupled. When you say you want to receive messages in a button action, it's equivalent of saying "I don't really care when the publisher produced the message, but I'll listen when I feel like" - which doesn't fit the use of a JMS. May be a queue where you have messages and pick one after the other based on some user action.

The publisher will not mark the message as delivered (based on how you have configured it) until the client acknowledges it and in your case (even if it were possible), it may be a long time and the message might expire. One way to achieve this, with JMS, is to have your internal data structure where you keep all your messages (after picking them up from the topic using a listener) and then process it on a button action. But you'll lose all the benefits of a JMS provider (durability, loss of messages upon client shut down, and the likes).

Comment: It is perfectly fine to consume messages when you feel like it, if this is the business requirement. If a message expires prior of consuming it, it is a matter of overall application design to define the right expiration interval for the use cases to support.